# efficient way to remove a background from an image in python

Tags: python, image-processing, image-recognition

I've recently started working on my project of creating an efficient bot to play *bejeweled 2*, right now i'm stuck on a part in which i want my program to do image recognition, right now the idea is to take a picture of a current board, remove background from it and then tell what gem it is by shape, however when i try running the code using rembg, results were very bad, what should i do to have better results in removing background, heres a code very similiar to the one i tried using in main project (this one was used in testing )

[image: pre background remove 1]]
[image: post gg removal]

[image: entire screen before bg remove]
[image: entire screen after bg remove]

```
from rembg import remove
from PIL import Image
input_path = 'pic1.png'
output_path = 'pic2.png' //not actual names
input = Image.open(input_path)

output = remove(input)

output.save(output_path)

print('done')
```

Comment: rembg was trained on different problems, no wonder it does not work. Read more about it here: https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg.

Comment: It is working on the remove.bg, I tested. You can use their API for this problem.